# Can I Use RxAndroidBle and RxJava2 in the same project?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I have an Android application which relies on RxAndroid (based on RxJava2).
I've also added the RxAdnroidBle dependency which [still uses RxJava1](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/72).

During compilation I had the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
    File1: /home/eddy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.1.0/2fdf84dedcaaeabb9d70cde9dbb8aad4eccb80a1/rxjava-2.1.0.jar
    File2: /home/eddy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.3.0/af000bec2036a2a9d07197c4b03b8966bfc60b03/rxjava-1.3.0.jar
```

Which I [solved](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/334) by adding the following block to `build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```

I seems that everything works fine. But just to make sure - having both RxJava 1 & 2 libraries as dependencies may cause any problems?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They live in different packages, so you can use them together

From oficial documentation

> To allow having RxJava 1.x and RxJava 2.x side-by-side, RxJava 2.x is
>   under the maven coordinates io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.y and
>   classes are accessible below io.reactivex

Here we can see they can be side-by-side in one project

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks! can't believe that I missed that line.